# How to disable drawer button in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

so I have an app with this app bar that has this Button. When the user presses the button, it will open the drawer. However, when you just swipe to the left, it will also open the drawer.

This is the picture : [The Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwYw2.jpg)

And this is my code :

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          "AppBar",
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 30,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontFamily: "FjallaOne"),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFFF0D5EAF),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: ScrollView(),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            Text(
              "Hello world",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

**How do I disable the button**? I just want the user to swipe left, but the button is not shown on the screen.

Any answers is appreciated , thank you !

Comment: Set the `AppBar`'s `automaticallyImplyLeading` to `false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide your AppBars leading by setting `automaticallyImplyLeading` property to `false`

`automaticallyImplyLeading: false`

Full example based on your code

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Text(
          "AppBar",
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 30,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontFamily: "FjallaOne"),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFFF0D5EAF),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: ScrollView(),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            Text(
              "Hello world",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

case 1: if You want the button but still don't want anything to happen on that

```
 return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          "AppBar",
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 30,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontFamily: "FjallaOne"),
        ),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.menu),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFFF0D5EAF),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Container(),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            Text(
              "Hello world",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

case 2: if You don't want button at all

```
return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(
              "AppBar",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 30,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontFamily: "FjallaOne"),
            ),
            leading: Container(),
            backgroundColor: Color(0xFFF0D5EAF),
          ),
          body: Container(
            child: Container(),
          ),
          drawer: Drawer(
            child: ListView(
              children: [
                Text(
                  "Hello world",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
```